# Django UUIDField in admin search_fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

In a model I have a `UUIDField` like this:

```
uuid = models.UUIDField(_('UUID'), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

in corresponding adminisration I would to search by uuid value. So I have:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    search_fields = ('uuid',)
```

but in this way it does not produce any results. Have I to set somethink?
I use Django 1.11

Answer (score 9):

When showing a UUIDField in the admin site via `list_display` and likely in other places too, Django formats the UUID with dashes so it's possible you're searching with dashes. However, it is stored without dashes in the database and if you do a search without dashes it should work as expected.

If you don't like the discrepancy in the `list_display` output you can consider changing the way it's displayed (untested):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(_('UUID'), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def clean_uuid(self):
        return self.uuid.replace('-', '')

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('clean_uuid',)
    search_fields = ('uuid',)
```

Comment: Good answear. One more thing. 

you can user replace on strings, so you have convert UUID into string e.g. 
`return str(self.uuid).replace('-', '')`

Comment: even better would be to use `self.uuid.hex` ;)